# how to perform localization based on ceiling

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbdslamv2, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen localization based on the ceiling image mentioned a few places[1],[2] but its not clear to me if a ros package like RGBDSLAM or RTABMAP can be used with a kinect pointing at the ceiling ?
If not, is there another package that can be used to perform SLAM and then localization based on the ceiling ?

[1] https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub1/thrun_sebastian_1999_1/thrun_sebastian_1999_1.pdf
[2] http://www.iros2014.org/program/kinect-robot-navigation-contest

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222754/how-to-perform-localization-based-on-ceiling/) by [robotSamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/23419/robotsamir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

RGBDSLAM and RTABMAP are visual features-based SLAM, so if the ceiling has enough visual features and there are some discrimitive area (for localization/loop closure), they may work. The ceiling must be also in the depth range of the camera.

Note that RTABMAP can also work with only a RGB camera to detect loop closures (localization). This mode could be used to localize the robot based purely on the location appearance (e.g., it will tell that you are "near" a location in the map, without transformation estimation).

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotSamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/23419/robotsamir/) on 2016-01-19**:
Mathieu,where can I find instructions to perform map building and localization using a single RGB camera ?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-19**:
Search MonoSLAM keyword. Some newest open source approaches: [ORB_SLAM](http://webdiis.unizar.es/%7Eraulmur/orbslam/) and [LSD-SLAM](http://vision.in.tum.de/research/vslam/lsdslam)